# Uninstall bspwm

Tags: prompt, kali-linux

im new in linux, kali. i tried installing bspwm with autoBspwm but when i tried running the bspwm session it just freezed. i uninstalled bspwm with following commands:
`$ sudo apt-get remove bspwm` 
`$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove bspwm` 
`$ sudo apt-get purge bspwm` 
`$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove bspwm` 
it succesfully uninstalled bspwm but i still get the personalized prompt into the xterm, it only applies to the non root terminal so i installed oh my bash, and doesnt liked so uninstalled it but the prompt stills modified. cannot restore it to the default one.
how can i do that? i also tried changing the .bashrc with a default one but when i run "`source .bashrc`" it only show me errors.
PD: sorry if my english isnt good, im not a native speaker. ty

just want to get my default xterm back. ty